# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined when i put default prop

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I try to create a custom hook

```
const useX({name}) = () =>{ 
return name??"no name";
}
```

Then i use:

```
const customHook = useX();
```

Exist any way to create a functional component with optional props without typescript?
I try it, but get same error:

```
const useX({name:"DEFAULT"}) 
const useX({name:""})
const useX({name:{})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be there are a few syntax errors in your code. try this code:-

```
const useX = ({ name = "DEFAULT" } = {}) => {
  return name ?? "no name";
};
```

Comment: Thank you!! can you explain me why is necessary  " = {} " ?
In addition to the fact that this marks all the props as optional, shouldn't it be enough to assign them a default value so that this does not happen with the other props?

Comment: The = {} syntax in the function parameter is used to provide a default value for the entire parameter. In this case, it's creating a default object ({}) if no argument is provided when calling the function. This is crucial because it prevents the "Cannot read properties of undefined" error.